# How to get index of the first column that satisfies condition

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have A df like this:

```
ID | one | two | three  
A  | 1   | 0   |   3  
B  | 3   | 1   |   4  
C  | 4   | 3   |   2
```

How can I get the index of the first column where value is greater than 2? So that as a result O could get this kind of relation:

```
ID | COLNUM  
A  |  3    
B  |  1   
C  |  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
df.set_index('ID').lt(2).idxmin(axis=1)

ID
A    three
B      one
C      one
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.argmax` to get the integer index:

```
dfB = dfA['ID'].to_frame()

dfB['COLNUM'] = np.argmax(dfA.iloc[:,1:].gt(2).values, axis=1) + 1
```